# how to prove the operator $L$ is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Problem**
For 
$f, g \in C([0; 1])$ 
define
$$d(f,g):= \int_{0}^{1}\min\{1,\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert\}dx $$
(a) Prove that $d$ is a distance on $C([0,1]).$

(b) Let $L: C([0,1])\to \mathbb{R}$ 
be a linear operator, continuous with respect to the topology induced by 
$d$. Prove that $L = 0.$

**The part (a) is easy to solve. But I have no idea how to start for part (b). Please leave some hints, not a whole solution, to me.**

Comment: Well scalar multiplication is linear.  Try to see why $f\mapsto \lambda f$ is not continuous for $\lambda\neq0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the continuity of $L$, pick $\delta > 0$ such that $|L(f)|<1$ whenever $d(f,0)<\delta$. One sufficient condition for $d(f,0)<\delta$ is that $f$ satisfy the following property:

> **Property $P_{\delta}$.** The support of $f$ is contained in an interval of length $<\delta$. To be precise, there exists an interval $I\subseteq [0,1]$ of length $<\delta$ such that $ \{x : f(x) \neq 0 \} \subseteq I $.

If $f$ has this property, then so is *any* scalar multiple of $f$, hence

$$ |L(f)| = \frac{1}{n}|L(nf)| \leq \frac{1}{n} $$

and we have $L(f)=0$ by letting $n\to\infty$.

Now the key idea is that any continuous function $f$ can be uniformly approximated by linear combinations of functions having poperty $P_{\delta}$.

For instance, for each $n$ satisfying $n>2/\delta$, we notice that the linear interpolation $f_n$ of points $(\frac{k}{n}, f(\frac{k}{n}))$ for $k = 0, \cdots, n$ can be written by

$$f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\varphi_{n,k}(x), \qquad \varphi_{n,k}(x) := \max\left\{0, 1-n\left|x-\frac{k}{n}\right|\right\}.$$

Since each $\varphi_{n,k}$ is supported on the interval $[\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n}]$ whose length is $=\frac{2}{n} < \delta$, it has property $P_{\delta}$ and hence $L(\varphi_{n,k})=0$. So it follows that $L(f_n) = 0$. On the other hand, we can easily check that $f_n \to f$ uniformly and hence $f_n \to f$ under the metric $d$. So we have $L(f)=0$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks for stepping in. My proof was based on the notion that $C([0, 1])$ with this topology is a TVS, which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelLee, Thank you for the comment :)

Comment: @SangchulLee thank you. 
I thought that we should use the following theorem. 
To every functional $L$ on $C([0,1])$, correspondingly, there is a finite positive measure$\mu$ on $I=[0,1]$ such that $Lf=\int_{0}^{1}fd\mu\; \; f\in C(I)$

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari, Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem requires that $C([0,1])$ be equipped with the sup-norm topology. In our case, the topology on $C([0,1])$ is characterized by convergence in measure. (That is, our $C([0,1])$ is understood as subset of $L^0([0,1])$.) So the representation theorem does not work here.

Comment: @SangchulLee would you mind telling that why our functions in this problem have the $P_{\delta}$ property?

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari, Notice that the function $\varphi_{n,k}=f(k/n)\max\{0,1-n|x-\frac{k}{n}|\}$ takes non-zero value only on the interval $(\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n})$, whose length is $\frac{2}{n} < \delta$ by our restriction on $n$. So each $\varphi_{n,k}$ has property $P_{\delta}$.